# What Should the name of the START_TAG be when parsing an XML file

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse this XML file but get an error for START_TAG.
What should I set the name for the START_TAG to this XML file

> ```
> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {null}rss version="2.0" (position:START_TAG <rss version='2.0'>@2:20 in java.io.InputStreamReader@3a7a4ee3)
> ```

```
public ArrayList<Article> parse(InputStream is) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException, ParseException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

private ArrayList<Article> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException, ParseException {
    ArrayList<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG,ns,"rss version=\"2.0\"");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("item")) {
            articles.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return articles;
}
```

Here is a link to the XML file

http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=aapl,yhoo,fb,goog,hbcp,mcd,msft,nflx,t&region=US&lang=en-US

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out my START_TAG need to be:

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG,ns,"rss");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
```

and I also needed another while loop

```
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG,ns,"channel");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
```